# Вывод массива в обратном порядке

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

```
function yearsBirthDayList() {
 var data = new Array();

 for(i = 1905; i < 1998; i++) {
  data.push([i, i]);
 }

 return data;
}
```

Массив выводится в порядке:

```
[[1905,1905]-[1997,1997]]
```

Как сделать чтобы он выводился в обратном порядке?

```
[[1997,1997]-[1905,1905]]
```

Comment: вам именно отсортировать или именно в обратном порядке?

Comment: @Etki, в обратном порядке.

Comment: жесть. а нельзя цикл в обратную сторону сделать и заполнить как надо с самого начала? а то можно еще в sql зафигачить и там сортировать...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Первое, что приходит на ум.

```
var source = [1, 2, 3],
    inverse;

inverse = source.reduce(function (carrier, element) {
    carrier.unshift(element);
    return carrier;
}, []);

// inverse = [3, 2, 1]
```

upd второе, что приходит на ум:

```
var source = [1, 2, 3];
source.reverse();
```

обратите внимание, что в этом случае исходный массив будет модифицирован (в то время как в первом примере создается второй массив). Чтобы создать новый, можно воспользоваться `slice` с первого же элемента:

```
var source = [1, 2, 3],
    inverse;

inverse = source.slice(0).reverse();
```

Comment: reverse() самое то. Спасибо.